# Calling R writeRaster from Python with rpy2

Tags: python, rpy2, r-raster

I am using an R package within my Python code to import, process and save a GeoTIFF raster. The importing and processing works just fine, but I struggle to save the raster file again. This is a simplified version of the code I'm running:

```html
import rpy2.rinterface as ri
import rpy2.robjects as rob
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages

raster  = rpackages.importr('raster')

r_raster = raster.raster(geotiff_input_path)

# r_raster = process_raster(r_raster)

raster.writeRaster(r_raster, geotiff_output_path, overwrite=True)
```

However, the code fails with `AttributeError: module 'raster' has no attribute 'writeRaster'`.

I seem to misunderstand how to call `writeRaster` properly.

Comment: try this:  https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/writing.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This would require me to first transform the raster from the R space into Python space, right? The main problem is that I am calling R from Python via rpy2, and I would like to keep all the raster operations in R, as I am using a very specific package for processing.

Comment: I would do all my operations from `Python` and not `R`. However, *this is a personal choice* based on popularity, community & resources and others might disagree with such.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by calling the `writeRaster` function from within a R object:

```
import os
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

os.environ['R_HOME'] = r'C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.3'

raster = importr('raster')
    
robjects.globalenv["rasterpath"] = rasterpath
robjects.globalenv["raster"] = raster
robjects.r('writeRaster(raster, rasterpath, format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)')
```

Once you declare the `robjects` with the `robjects.globalenv['']` function, you can use them as objects of your actual local variables. Therefore, you can write within the string with R notation.